# Which sentence sounds better?

Tags: grammar, word-order

Can someone kindly tell me which of the two sentences is more grammatically correct (and why)?

1. As such, I was challenged to develop exercises more suited to my audience.
2. As such, I was challenged to develop more appropriately suited exercises.

Thank you!

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, they're both equal as far as correctness goes, and they seem pretty correct to me. But *style-wise*, I prefer the first.

First of all, though, you didn't ask, but the beginning of each sentence is a bit weak. (And I'm talking only about style here.)

> As such, I was challenged to...

"As such" doesn't sound too idiomatic to me, and I can't picture what came before for it to fit there. And "I was ..." is *passive* voice, which we try to avoid as much as possible in English, in favor of active voice.

Now, to the rest: the first sentence is better because (1) "exercises" follows directly after "develop", so it's easier on the reader. And (2) "more suited" makes it immediately obvious what "more" is referring to, whereas in the second sentence, "more" (for just a split second) seems like it might be referring to quantity of something...

Comment: Hi Johnny, Thank you for your explanation. It was very helpful. Fyi: The sentence that precedes this one is: "It didn't' take long for me see/realize that traditional exercises failed to adequately meet the needs of persons with disabilities." Within this sentence, I'm having trouble deciding on whether to use "see" or "realize." Any thoughts?

Comment: "to realize" seems better for this topic and tone you're setting. And yep, for sure, think about the "I was challenged." Did your boss challenge you? Was this a challenge you placed on yourself? Possibly it was an _unexpected_ but _fun_ challenge that the situation presented to you? Just giving you ideas. I like to start sentences like that with "And so," but that's unconventional. "Therefore" works too.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your input/feedback.